# How to isolate a certain part of a string and print it?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm using the pyowm module to scrape weather data from OpenWeatherMap. It works fine, but when I request the weather, it outputs it in this format

```
<pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather - reference time=2015-10-28 18:01:16+00, status=rain>
```

is there a to, for example, grab the words "rain" or "cloudy" by assigning the letters between the "=" and closing tag(>) to a new variable and then printing this new variable?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to parse the string to get the data you want. What you currently have is an object of type [`pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather`](http://pyowm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyowm.webapi25.html#module-pyowm.webapi25.weather). You can access its fields like so:

```
print weather_obj.get_reference_time()
print weather_obj.get_status()
```

(where `weather_obj` is the name of your object.)

The the [documentation](http://pyowm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pyowm.webapi25.html#module-pyowm.webapi25.weather) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
x="<pyowm.webapi25.weather.Weather - reference time=2015-10-28 18:01:16+00, status=rain>"
print re.findall(r"(?<==)[^=]*(?=>)",x)
```

You can use `re` with `lookbehind` for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the index of the last occurrence of "=" and ">" by calling:

```
lastEqualIndex = weatherString.rfind("=")
lastLTIndex = weatherString.rfind(">")
```

Then what you want is just:

```
weather = weatherString[lastEqualIndex + 1, lastLTIndex]
```